# RTF file to TXT/CSV file in objective-c?

Tags: ios, csv, rtf, file-conversion

I have RTF files containing that sort of content:

```
long_text_description_1     number1a        number1b        number1c
long_text_description_2     number2a        number2b        number2c
long_text_description_3                                     number3c
long_text_description_4     number4a        number4b        number4c
…
```

I need to extract the plain raw text without the colours, fonts and other formatting thing.
The only thing I need to keep are the most basic row/column information, ideally I would like a CSV file.

The file I get contain all the formatting:

```
{\cs18\lang1033\langfe1033\f0\b\i0\ul0\strike0\scaps0\fs15\afs15\charscalex100\expndtw0\cf1\dn0 number1a}
```

What is the best way to remove all rtf information while only keeping the row information?
Trying to figure out myself many many regular expressions sound dangerous unless there is a complete understanding of the RTF format.

What I could find on the Internet mostly focused on using Windows languages & libraries unavailable in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

All rtf tags are in the form `\xxx`.
Try using a regular expression like "\\S+" and remove all matches or replace with nothing.
For your example, you'll end up with `{ number1a}` This will remove any backslash followed by any characters.

Comment: It should work but I would loose the \row, \cell and a few other related ones that would make me loose line breaks/tabbing information (which I must keep if I want to retain col/row information). Also I would loose text that contain backslash. But Thanks!

Comment: got another file format now so less important to me. I still find strange that the format is not better defined. Also parsing it manually, using regex and no exhaustive knowledge of the format specs sound "non-trivial"...

Comment: I don't know about objective-c but what I would do in c# is to set the `RTF` property of a temp richtextbox to the data you have, and then read its `Text` property. This will only get the plain text.

Comment: If you mean the RTF spec, here is one version: http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm